# Create Passenger Name Record 2.4.0 REST API in Sabre CERT Error Response

Tags: rest, postman, sabre

I am getting following error while creating a PNR with Air segment in **POSTMAN** using REST API Create Passenger Name Record 2.4.0:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ERR.SP.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED",
  "message": "Parsing error occurred",
  "status": "NotProcessed",
  "type": "Validation",
  "timeStamp": "2022-08-04T16:08:45-05"
}
```

POST:

https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.4.0/passenger/records?mode=create

Param:

mode: create

Header:

Authorization: Bearer T1RLAQKQ/Dz6Qr2tT/+FGEW+nhird66Zt7wYF5vyA/oFBHpF2Y2KS1VoWo/R3dIp5EdQS9W/NyAtm7100u0GSsNcM
Content-Type: application/json

Body:

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.4.0",
    "targetCity": "UQ2H",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": false,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "SABRE TRAVEL",
          "CityName": "SOUTHLAKE",
          "CountryCode": "US",
          "PostalCode": "76092",
          "StateCountyProv": {
            "StateCode": "TX"
          },
          "StreetNmbr": "3150 SABRE DRIVE"
        },
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "Phone": "202-555-0137",
            "PhoneUseType": "H"
          }
        },
        "PersonName": {
          "NameNumber": "1.1",
          "NameReference": "ABC123",
          "PassengerType": "ADT",
          "GivenName": "WIELGACHNY",
          "Surname": "DZIK"
        }
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "HaltOnStatus": {
        "Code": "HL"
      },
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": {
          "ArrivalDateTime": "2022-10-09T15:11:00",
          "DepartureDateTime": "2022-10-09T19:27:00",
          "FlightNumber": "2923",
          "NumberInParty": "1",
          "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
          "Status": "NN",
          "DestinationLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "DFW"
          },
          "MarketingAirline": {
            "Code": "AA",
            "FlightNumber": "2923"
          },
          "OriginLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "LAS"
          }
        }
      },
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "NumAttempts": 10,
        "WaitInterval": 300
      }
    },
    "AirPrice": {
      "PriceRequestInformation": {
        "Retain": true,
        "OptionalQualifiers": {
          "FOP_Qualifiers": {
            "BasicFOP": {
              "Type": "CK"
            }
          },
          "PricingQualifiers": {
            "PassengerType": {
              "Code": "ADT",
              "Quantity": "1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "PaymentInformation": {
      "FormOfPayment": {
        "PaymentCard": {
          "PaymentType": "CC",
          "CardCode": "AX",
          "CardNumber": "371305480902000",
          "ExpiryMonth": 12,
          "ExpiryYear": "2022",
          "FullCardHolderName": {
            "FirstName": "WIELGACHNY",
            "LastName": "DZIK",
            "Email": "services.platform.test@sabre.com"
          },
          "CSC": "7777",
          "Address": {
            "AddressLine": "Wadowicka",
            "CityName": "Krakow",
            "StateProvince": {
              "code": "KR"
            },
            "StateProvinceCodes": {
              "Code": {
                "content": "KR"
              }
            },
            "PostCode": "30-415",
            "CountryCodes": {
              "Code": {
                "content": "PL"
              }
            }
          },
          "Phone": {
            "PhoneNumber": "202-555-0137"
          }
        }
      },
      "Type": "GUARANTEE"
    }
  },
  "MiscSegment": {
    "VendorPrefs": {
      "Airline": {
        "Code": "AS"
      }
    },
    "DepartureDateTime": "03-14",
    "NumberInParty": 1,
    "Text": "TEST OTH MISCELLANEOUS SEGMENT",
    "Type": "OTH",
    "OriginLocation": {
      "LocationCode": "ORD"
    },
    "Status": "GK"
  },
  "SpecialReqDetails": {
    "AddRemark": {
      "RemarkInfo": {
        "FOP_Remark": {
          "Type": "CHECK"
        }
      }
    },
    "SpecialService": {
      "SpecialServiceInfo": {
        "SecureFlight": {
          "SegmentNumber": "A",
          "PersonName": {
            "DateOfBirth": "1990-01-01",
            "Gender": "M",
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "GivenName": "WIELGACHNY",
            "Surname": "DZIK"
          },
          "VendorPrefs": {
            "Airline": {
              "Hosted": true
            }
          }
        },
        "Service": {
          "SSR_Code": "OTHS",
          "Text": "CC WIELGACHNY DZIK"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "PostProcessing": {
    "ARUNK": {},
    "EndTransaction": {
      "Source": {
        "ReceivedFrom": "SP TEST"
      }
    },
    "RedisplayReservation": {
      "waitInterval": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.5.0",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": false,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW",
          "ShortText": "Travelocity Main Office"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "Phone": "0512120448",
              "PhoneUseType": "M"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Email": [
          {
            "Address": "attaullahafridi94@gmail.com"
          }
        ],
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "NameReference": "",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "Kabir Mr",
            "Surname": "Aarav"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "RetryRebook": {
        "Option": true
      },
      "HaltOnStatus": [
        {
          "Code": "HL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "KK"
        },
        {
          "Code": "LL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NN"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NO"
        },
        {
          "Code": "UC"
        },
        {
          "Code": "US"
        }
      ],
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": [
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2024-01-16T12:45:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2024-01-16T11:00:00",
            "FlightNumber": "303",
            "NumberInParty": "1",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
            "Status": "NN",
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "KHI"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "PK",
              "FlightNumber": "303"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "LHE"
            }
          },
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2024-01-16T23:59:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2024-01-16T22:30:00",
            "FlightNumber": "603",
            "NumberInParty": "1",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
            "Status": "NN",
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "DXB"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "EK",
              "FlightNumber": "603"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "KHI"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "NumAttempts": 10,
        "WaitInterval": 300
      }
    },
    "AirPrice": [
      {
        "PriceRequestInformation": {
          "Retain": true,
          "OptionalQualifiers": {
            "FOP_Qualifiers": {
              "BasicFOP": {
                "Type": "CA"
              }
            },
            "PricingQualifiers": {
              "PassengerType": [
                {
                  "Code": "ADT",
                  "Quantity": "1"
                }
              ],
              "SpecificPenalty": {
                "EitherOr": {
                  "Any": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
      "SpecialService": {
        "SpecialServiceInfo": {
          "SecureFlight": [
            {
              "SegmentNumber": "A",
              "PersonName": {
                "DateOfBirth": "2011-11-04",
                "Gender": "M",
                "NameNumber": "1.1",
                "GivenName": "Kabir Mr",
                "Surname": "Aarav"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "waitInterval": 100
      },
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "WebBooking"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```